# Solr Field exists syntax - * vs [* TO *]

Tags: solr

I'm trying to write a query which checks if a certain field exist in a document. The field is known only on query time and can be of different types: int,string,bool, multi-value/single value.
I'm familiar with 2 syntax for doing this which both seems to work:

1. `my_field:*`
2. `my_field:[* TO *]`

What's the difference between the two?

This for Solr v5 (and higher)

Comment: Well, there are no differences between my_field:* and my_field:[* TO *]

Comment: Thanks, do you have any source for that claim?

Comment: you can test it in solr directly. It will give you the same results for both queries.

Comment: I've done that, however my question is if there is anything different "behind the scenes", maybe on performance wise or anything other effects which I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> `field:[* TO *]` finds any document with a value between the effective
> values of -Infinity and +Infinity for that field type.

and

> For most fields, unbounded range queries, `field:[* TO *]`, are
> equivalent to existence queries, `field: *` . However, for float/double
> types that support NaN values, these two queries perform differently.
>
> - `field:*` matches all existing values, including NaN
> - `field:[* TO *]` matches all real values, excluding NaN

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/standard-query-parser.html#range-searches

So there is a diffrence in how the search query is definied and maybe also how the search is performed, but in most of the cases the behaviour is the same.